# Question about the frequency definition of probability

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, proportion, frequency, definition

In the book, it is written that the relative frequency or the frequency ratio gradually tends to become more or less constant as N becomes larger and larger. It is also mentioned that this is an empirical fact.
My question is: why should the frequency ratio tend to a constant in the long run ? I mean, there isn't any *convergence proof* working after all (is there ?).

Comment: Well, if you notice that the sample proportion is a kind of average, [actually](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) there is, but that might seem a little circular in the case of the weak law. (On the other hand that definition doesn't rely on the frequency definition of probability.)

Comment: I have always found it amusing and instructive, to try to imagine what the world would be like if the law of large numbers did not hold.

Comment: @Alecos Papadopoulos: Inside this six volumes https://books.google.no/books?id=_P7XswEACAAJ&dq=sigma+james+R+newman&hl=no&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj1stnE9t_cAhURxqYKHTg7DWQQ6AEILjAB  there is a short story about such a world!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I find that Newman's book is four volumes, everywhere I look. Why are you saying six volumes?

Comment: The version I bought (but that was a translation to swedish) was six volumes. Maybe the english original was different?